# Check if mousedown() event happened on certain element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events

I'm using this function to detect `mousedown()` and initialize content drag:

```
        var mouseDown = false;
        var prevCoords = { x: 0, y: 0 };

        $("#mainDiv").mousedown(function() {
            mouseDown = true;
        }).mousemove(function(e) {
            var currentScrollX = $('#mainDiv').scrollLeft();
            var currentScrollY = $('#mainDiv').scrollTop();
            if(mouseDown) { 
                $('#mainDiv').scrollLeft(currentScrollX + prevCoords.x - e.clientX)
                $('#mainDiv').scrollTop(currentScrollY + prevCoords.y - e.clientY)
            };
            prevCoords.x = e.clientX;
            prevCoords.y = e.clientY;
        }).mouseup(function() {
            mouseDown = false;
        });
```

But `#mainDiv` contains `.foo` tables which are draggable itself. How do I check, if `mousedown()` happened on `.foo` table? In this case `mouseDown` should become `false` to cancel content drag. I have tried this but it did not work:

```
        $("#mainDiv").mousedown(function() {
            if($('.foo').mousedown()){
                mouseDown = false;
            }
            else{
                mouseDown = true;
            }
```

Comment: You can filter inside click handler which child element (if any) has triggered event using e.g: `if($(event.target).closest('.foo').length) return;` and passing `event` as handler argument, so try: `$("#mainDiv").mousedown(function(event) {if($(event.target).closest('.foo').length) return; //else not: following logic there...});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check which element caused the event that bubbled up to `#mainDiv` you can check the `target` of the event. You can also make the logic a little tidier:

```
$("#mainDiv").mousedown(function(e) {
  mousedown = !$(e.target).closest('.foo').length;
});
```

Comment: It should be: `mousedown = !$(e.target).closest('.foo').length;`

Comment: True, that would cover situations where cells within the table are clicked. I'll update to cover both scenarios, as it's still possible to click the table directly - on a border, for example.

Comment: But you have to remove `!$target.is('.foo') &&` otherwise `!$target.closest('.foo').length` has no meaning :)

Comment: Yep, you're right. It wasn't needed anyway as after reading the docs `closest()` already includes the current element.

Comment: Got there in the end :) Glad to help